# Reading a zero member from a jsonp object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, jsonp

I am querying an API requesting JSONP (using $resource from angular if that's important) which seems to work fine.
Logging the returned object to the console shows me an object with all the data, but I have trouble accessing it.

The problem is that it returns not just the data, but the object holds  another object called 0 which holds the actual data I am after and I don't know how to access it.

I tried 
console.log(serie.0.title) (serie is the returned object, title is one data-field)
console.log(serie[0].title) and a few other ways but of course nothing works.

The image shows my firefox console with the expanded returned object. (Also two more objects, which are just results of two more jsonp calls.)

[image: firefox console showing the logged jsonp object]

Comment: Your object is an **array**.  That's what the square brackets (`[ ]`) around the value mean. Zero is the first index in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is an array. So for example to get the first element you could use:

```
var title = serie[0].title;
```

and if you wanted to loop through all elements:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < seri.length; i++) {
    var item = serie[i];
    // access some property of the item such as item.title here
}
```

Comment: @Pointy, I guess it's a property of some of the elements of this array. Without further context from the OP it's hard to know :-) It would have been much easier if the OP has provided his JSON object instead of showing some Firefox screenshots but alas.

Comment: I don't know what to say. As stated above: I already tried that. Now I tried it again et voila, works. I am so ashamed... :( Thanks alot for the quick answer, though!